# Android ViewPager: Destroyed Fragment still contains user input

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm developing an Android App, where the user can save, how many hours he/she worked per day. Through a month overview you can get to a day detail view (i.e. by tapping on a day in `MonthRecordActivity` you get to the `DayRecordActivity` for the choosen day). The DayActivity uses `ViewPager` so slide to the previous or next day.

Each `DayRecordFragment` is connected to a `TimerecordModel` Object which is used for databinding. Everytime the user input will be stored in the corresponding TimerecordModel. There is a Save-Button to send the data to a database and if the data is not saved, it should be removed from the locally stored TimerecordModel's as well.

### The problem scenario

The user sees the `DayRecordActivity` for April 12th 2016 and puts in "4" into the `EditText` labeled with "Hours Extern". This is stored in the TimerecordModel (as soon as he changes the focus to another another `EditText` because the "4" has to be converted to "4.0"). He doesn't use the Save-Button. Then he slides to the right and sees the April 13th view and another time to see April 14th. Now the fragment for April 12th is destroyed, because only the actual, previous and next day are stored. The `onDestroyView()` from `DayRecordFragmet` is called and the unsaved 4 hours are deleted with the method `revertUnsavedChanges()`.

However, when I slide back to April 12th I still SEE the 4 hours in the extern field. They are only in the view; when I try to send them with the Save-Button I get the error "Cannot save empty timerecord". And when I go back to the Month overview, there are no hours shown for April 12th. I just have to reset the view. How do I do this?

#### TimerecordModel (Databinding class)

```
public class TimerecordModel extends BaseObservable{

private Timerecord timerecord;
private TimerecordBackup backup; // just a data structure
private boolean hasChanged = false;
private boolean hasUnsavedChanges = false;

public TimerecordModel(Timerecord timerecord) {
    this.timerecord = timerecord;
    if (timerecord != null) backup = new TimerecordBackup(timerecord);
}

public void applyChanges(){
    hasUnsavedChanges = false;
    backup = new TimerecordBackup(timerecord);
}

public void revertUnsavedChanges(){
    hasUnsavedChanges = false;

    timerecord.setHoursIntern(backup.hoursIntern);
    timerecord.setHoursExtern(backup.hoursExtern);
    timerecord.setHoursSick(backup.hoursSick);
    timerecord.setHoursHoliday(backup.hoursHoliday);
    timerecord.setHoursTraining(backup.hoursTraining);
    timerecord.setTrainingName(backup.trainingName);
    timerecord.setComment(backup.comment);

    notifyChange();
}

public Timerecord getTimerecord() {
    return timerecord;
}

// Getter/Setter for unbound variables
// simply get values from timerecord and set them in timerecord

// .............

// Getter/Setter for bound variables
// get values from timerecord
// when setting values in timerecord, notify listener to update view accordingly

@Bindable
public Double getHoursExtern() {
    return this.timerecord.getHoursExtern();
}

public void setHoursExtern(Double hoursExtern) {
    hasUnsavedChanges = true;
    this.timerecord.setHoursExtern(hoursExtern);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hoursExtern);
}

// Other getters and setters for bound variables

//...........

// Some helper methods

public boolean hasChanged() {
    return hasChanged;
}

public boolean hasUnsavedChanges(){ return hasUnsavedChanges; }

public Double getWorkHours() {...}

public Double getHoursSum() {...}

public boolean isEmpty() {...}

private Double getDouble(View v) {
    String value =((EditText) v).getText().toString().replace(",", ".");
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (value.length() - value.replace(".", "").length() > 1) {
        return null;
    }
    return Double.valueOf(value);
}

// Watcher used to notice change of values
public final TextWatcher changed = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        hasChanged = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
};


// Listeners used to set value of variables after change in view

public final View.OnFocusChangeListener hoursExternChanged = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus && hasChanged) {
            setHoursExtern(getDouble(v));
            hasChanged = false;
        }
    }
};
// more OnFocusChangeListeners to come....


}
```

#### DayRecordFragment

In the `onCreate()` the databinding connection to a `TimerecordModel` object is created. A new object will be created, if there are no entries yet (which is the case, when I swipe back from April 14th to April 12th in my example). Otherwise it will load the existing timerecord from a local Hashmap.

In `onPause()` I check, if there are unsaved changes and revert them if necessary. This happens, when I swipe from April 12th to April 14th.

```
public class DayRecordFragment extends Fragment implements CustomFragment {
private TimerecordModel timerecordModel = new TimerecordModel();
private Date recordDate;

@Override
public DayRecordFragment newInstance(int position) {
    DayRecordFragment fragment = new DayRecordFragment();
    savePositionOfFragment(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

private void savePositionOfFragment(int position, DayRecordFragment fragment) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt("page_position", position);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    recordDate = calculateDateOfDayViewInstance();
    timerecordModel = getTimerecordFor(recordDate);
    
    // Databinding to TimerecordModel
    ActivityDayTimeRecordBinding mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.activity_day_time_record, container, false);
    mBinding.setTimerecord(timerecordModel);

    // some view initiations
    View rootView = mBinding.getRoot();
    if (DateUtil.isWeekend(recordDate) || DateUtil.isHoliday(recordDate)) {
        disableSicknessVacation(rootView);
    }
    setBackgroundColor(rootView, recordDate);
    setToolbar(rootView, recordDate);
    initiateButtons(rootView);

    return rootView;
}

/*
if record for current day exists, use it
generate a blank one otherwise (needed for data binding)
 */
private TimerecordModel getTimerecordFor(Date recordDate){
    TimerecordModel timerecord = CpApp.getApplication().getTimerecord(recordDate);
    if (timerecord == null) {
        timerecord = new TimerecordModel(recordDate, CpApp.getApplication().getUser().getName());
        CpApp.getApplication().addTimerecord(timerecord.getTimerecord());
    }
    return timerecord;
}

/**
 * If blank timerecordModel is not needed anymore and still blank, kick it.
 */
@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (timerecordModel.hasUnsavedChanges()){
        timerecordModel.revertUnsavedChanges();

    }

    if (timerecordModel.isEmpty())
        CpApp.getApplication().deleteTimerecord(timerecordModel.getDate());

    super.onPause();
}

/**
 * Sets the toolbar with title and save button.
 * @param rootView - rootView of DayRecordFragment
 * @param day - day of fragment
 */
private void setToolbar(View rootView, Date day) {
    .....
}

/**
 * Used for Data Binding of doubles
 * Sets the EditText value, if value of bound variable changes.
 * @param editText - EditText bound to changed variable
 * @param value - new value of variable
 */
@BindingAdapter("binding")
public static void bindEditText(EditText editText, Double value) {
    if (value != null && !editText.getText().toString().equals(value.toString())) {
        editText.setText(value.toString().replace(".", ","));
    }
}

/**
 * Used for Data Binding of strings
 * Sets the EditText value, if value of bound variable changes.
 * @param editText - EditText bound to changed variable
 * @param value - new value of variable
 */
@BindingAdapter("binding")
public static void bindEditText(EditText editText, String value) {
    if (value != null && !editText.getText().toString().equals(value)) {
        editText.setText(value);
    }
}
}
```